# Missing mtb bottom bracket cable guide screw?

Tags: parts, diamondback

2016 Diamondback Haanjo Comp

I was giving the bike a bit of a wipedown today and noticed a missing screw on the bottom.

[image: From OP's link]

I've been unable to find any specifications such as this from DB.

Can I figure this out without taking it apart?  (I don't want to take the other screw out since it looks like I'd have a mess on my hands.

Does anybody have an idea what screw I need to get and where to get it?

Comment: I'd bet there's no hole in the frame nor threads for a screw to go into.   Good spotting though!

Comment: BTW: it's one of the places on a bike that needs attention with frequent cleaning and lubing, especially after a ride on dirty ground. It can only improve the shifting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are concerned about the empty hole next to the Phillips head screw, you can ease your concern. The cable guide typically only needs a single mounting screw. The extra hole allows the same cable guide to fit a variety of bikes by  shifting the guide towards the drive or non drive side depending on which hole is used.

Comment: Yeah, that was my concern!

Comment: Yeah, I've examined at least a dozen different bikes with this sort of cable guide, and I've never seen more than a single screw.

Comment: The tension of the inner cables mostly holds the fitting in place even without a screw.

Comment: DB confirmed that this is EXACTLY what the reason is.